# as3 crop image loaded as MC

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi this kills me :) I am using senocular for as3 move,rotate,scale,skew loaded image into MC and works great, but spent a lot of time, can't find nice solution for cropping such MC (with loaded image) with mouse. Do someone have solution (code) for this?

Comment: Do you want to just display the image as if it had been cropped, or do you need to alter (and then save) the actual image?

Comment: when load image, I need box whose sides can be moved left/right/up/down and on that way crop MC which stays on stage

Comment: Or in simple words, like senocular for transform http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformtool/ , justthis what I need is to crop MC on stage

Comment: But do you actually want to crop it (ie. create a subset of the pixel data so the MC can be encoded and saved as a jpeg or a png), or just display the cropped area? I'm asking because the former involves a bit of code, the latter is quite easy.

Comment: I need just to display cropped area

Comment: OK: so I've answered for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the cropped area, all you need to do is apply a mask, which is just another Display Object.

I haven't used Senocular's code for this, but if you make the **mask** the target of his move / scale code, then you can easily implement cropping. There's plenty on masking in the Adobe docs: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_28.html

In practice, you have to hide the resize / move controls when cropping, and vice-versa, which is why tools like Flash itself, or Photoshop, have separate transform and crop modes.

From Senocular's docs:

```
// import for the Transform Tool classes used
import com.senocular.display.transform.*;

// create a box object to interact with
var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(box);
box.graphics.beginFill(0xAACCDD);
box.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
box.x = 100;
box.y = 100;

// create the Transform Tool
var tool:TransformTool = new TransformTool(new ControlSetStandard());
addChild(tool);

// select the box with the transform tool when clicked. 
// deselect when clicking on the stage
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tool.select);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tool.deselect);
```

Just do this, but **box** needs to be the **mask** of your movie clip, so that when you resize it, you will crop the movie clip.

Comment: Huh, any example? If I understand I need to : 1) add mc 2) add mask to shape 3) get mouse cords when moving bounding box 4) manipulate with that coordinates on mc mask?

Comment: Simon - I'm on a deadline and I don't have time to put together a full example for you. Yes: 1) add mc, 2) add mask, 3) add Senocular's resize handles to the Mask, so the user can resize it, 4) Constrain the proportions so they can only resize the mask within the bounds of the MC, 5) When the mask is resized, the visible MC is cropped.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, everything is very cleat just tell me how to "add Senocular's resize handles to the Mask", I don't have idea how to do that?

Comment: I mean how to add just handleds with tool senocular tool functionality?

Comment: See above. I really can't do any more - it takes a while to program a cropping solution. I've built several, and the usually take several hours. I can't just do one for you now as a sample.

Comment: Huh again :) Thanks you gave me a clue, and now I am on "half" of way, so thanks a lot for this great hint(s)!

Comment: Glad to help. It's not the kind of question there is a really quick answer to.